# c# Windows7 Socket

Tags: c#, sockets, websocket

I have now connected the server of node.js to the c# client. Works normally on Windows 10 but not on Windows 7. Is there a good way to communicate this in Windows 7?

```
Error
System.PlattformNotSupportedException: WebSocket protocol is not supported on this platform.




private async Task OnConnected(string email)
       {
            try
            {
                var client = new SocketIO("https://URL"); 
                var loginjson = new JObject();   

                loginjson.Add("Str", email);

                await client.ConnectAsync();
                await Task.Delay(500);

                await client.EmitAsync("socketlogin", loginjson);

                client.On("login", res =>
                {
                    JObject jObj = JObject.Parse(res.Text);

                });
                await Task.Delay(300);
                await client.CloseAsync();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
            }
        }
```

Nugget's SocketIOClient was used and the above code showed a simple connection.

Comment: Windows 7 itself is not supported anymore, either...

Comment: I know, but you must make a connection...

Comment: Well the error makes it clear - websocket connections are not supported through this library in C#, on Windows 7. Not a lot you can do about that, unless you want to try and write your own library to implement the protocol yourself. Or search for another library which does work. My suggestion though is to use a supported platform.